# Angular JS working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just started learning about Angular JS. Though I can code up an Angular module, I have lot of questions on how Angular works.

1. How does $scope work? I understand that one root scope is created at the point of declaration of ng-module. This represents the DOM in some way and also watches the DOM for any changes in properties, events, etc.. How does this watch implemented?
2. How is it ensured that this scope object is ready once the page loads, so that it can be used by the controller? How does access permissions work with the scope object, cases where controller might not have access to a variable?
3. In which cases you might want to use an injector explicitly?
4. What's lifecycle of an angular app in detail? Is there any client side versus server side component or is it entirely client side? When I say, ng-repeat, this is still client side?

Comment: Angular is a **client** framework, see its Tutorial and Documentation at https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $scope is what angular uses to expose variables to the template. Think of scope as your 'view model'. Anything attached to the scope will be exposed. $scope uses prototyped inheritance. This means that children of a scope will have access to the parents properties. There are more detailed nuances to scope inheritance involving change detection.
2. Dependency injection solves the 'ready' problem. Angular takes care of injecting the scope properly in each controller already instantiated.
3. If you need to create a function that modifies a service when that service hasnt been instantiated yet. For example configuring an error handler. Only providers will be available, using the injector we can grab the service when the error is thrown.

`

```
function(rejection) {
    if (rejection.status === 401) {
        // have to lazy inject cause http interceptors are defined
        // at provider configuration
        var sessions = $injector.get('sessions');
        var $state = $injector.get('$state');
        sessions.logout().then(function() {
            $state.go('login');
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            });
        }
    }

    return $q.reject(rejection);
}
```

4. I recommend reading this documentation to shed some light on 'the angular way'. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope